# Sort taxonomy by post

Tags: php, wordpress

### Problem

I search in internet and cannot found solution to my problem. Wordpress has any solution to order taxonomy by post. For example: I have hotels from different countries. If user enter to the hotel in Uzbekistan taxonomy should come firstly Uzbekistan than other countries.

```
<div class="left_widget">
    <h2 class="second_title"><?=pll__('Destinations')?></h2>
        <ul class="left_menu">
            <li><a href="<?=get_permalink( get_id_by_slug('hotels-'.currlang()) )?>"><?=pll__('All Hotels')?></a></li>
            <?
            $categories = get_terms('destination', 'orderby=rand&hide_empty=0'); 


            if($categories){

            foreach ($categories as $cat):
                            ?>
            <li><a href="<?=get_permalink( get_id_by_slug('hotels-'.currlang()) )?>?h-destination=<?=$cat->name;?>"><?=$cat->name;?></a></li>
                <?
                endforeach;
                }
                ?>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you figuring out which country should be first?

However you are determining what country they are in or what country they are looking for hotels in, change your foreach loop like this:

```
$first_list = "";
ob_start();
foreach ($categories as $cat):
    if( $cat->name == $current_country_variable_name ) {
        $string = "<li><a href='" . get_permalink( get_id_by_slug("hotels-" .currlang()) ) . "?h-destination=" . $cat->name . "'>" . $cat->name . "</a></li>";
        $first_array .= $string;
    }
    else {
      ?>
      <li><a href="<?=get_permalink( get_id_by_slug('hotels-'.currlang()) )?>?h-destination=<?=$cat->name;?>"><?=$cat->name;?></a></li>
      <?
    }
 endforeach;

echo $first_list;
echo ob_get_clean();
```

I have not tested this, but this is my general idea. Let me know if it works for you.